# How to remap type into a new type

Tags: typescript, types

So i have a type, inside it I have so many properties, just for example

```
type SomeType = {
  First: {
    color: 'red' | 'blue'
  },
  Second: number,
  Third: {
    amount: number,
    size: 'small' | 'large'
  }[],
  Fourth: string,
  Fifth: string | number
}
```

then I want to create a new type but imitating from SomeType like this

```
type NewSomeType = {
  First: any,
  Second: any,
  Third: any,
  Fourth: any,
  Fifth: any
}
```

How to do it without hardcoding NewSomeType? I am having difficulty on research in this topic

Comment: So you want to lose the benefit of the typing system for the property value types, but keep the property keys defined? Why? How about `type PropertiesAsUnknown<T> = { [key in keyof T]: unknown; };` (I choose `unknown` over `any` because it prevents assigning the wrong type of value to another known type)

Comment: Thanks @j1mbl3s for the response, it's just for simpler example, in my real case i want to convert it into Promise<MyType>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  Specifically, for your example, you can write:

```
type NewSomeType = { [K in keyof SomeType]: any };
```

which evaluates to:

```
/* type NewSomeType = {
    First: any;
    Second: any;
    Third: any;
    Fourth: any;
    Fifth: any;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClAMQEsAnAZ2AC5s98oBjOAGzhOoHISIATdqAHyjsARkwCuEdrQC+AGlowIjAHbdqysQmEQS8-MgAWpNTTpQAhgjhjlVKBq069dMkQBeEDmQTmmTPoLsTOYkAOaSMgDaALrOBNYkwAbUFCREyqFxRABmSSnAaRkC9praJDjSODigkFAAchAA7vBIqLWYWFCRANJQ6VAA1hAgcNmwiCho0dTmyiBQ0gDcVQD0AFRQNdANzRNtGKZ0xOR2syDLZooqJmcXdIbGM3N3+PFiickWz7SvOXlf5wqUDWKyAA)